# running a python file and displaying it inside of a tkinter terminal instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot and this is what I want to do :
I want to have a gui that has a terminal inside and then I want to run the bot in that terminal
I tried using tkinter terminal and typing python bot_file_name.py but the problem with it is it runs the bot in another python program and not the one tkinter terminal is running in
(I want everything the bot prints get displayed in the tkinter window)

```
code:
import tkinter as tk
import tkterminal as tkt

bot_window = tk.Tk()
bot_terminal = tkt.Terminal()

bot_window.title("bot_name_interface")

bot_terminal.shell = True
bot_terminal.linebar = True
bot_terminal.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


bot_terminal.run_command("python main.py")


bot_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you should import bot code to this code and run it in separated thread and redirect outputs to tkinter widget like `Text` But all may depends on what you have in other script.

Comment: @furas something like that should work
can you please show me a code sample ?

Comment: I tested code with my `main.py` (which uses `print()`) and it displays text in terminal. What do you have in `main.py` ?

Comment: @furas it is just a discord.py bot
actully let me clarify it a little
So I have a discord.py bot at main.py
and this is what I want to have:
I want a tkinter gui that has some text and buttons
as well as a cmd display or a box that displays the cmd of main.py when it is run
and then I want to make the gui a seperate file and make it exe
So whenever I run gui.exe it does this:
first run main.py (discord.py bot)
then display everything in the bot cmd in the gui